# iis7 css is only applied to cassini server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7

If I run my site on IIS7.5 it renders exactly the same html as cassini server on VS2008:

```
<div class="toplistitem"> 
<p> 
Text presented on web page.
</p> 
</div>
```

with the following css class:

```
.toplistitem
{
background-color:rgb(230,230,230);
border-top:1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
border-left:1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
border-right:1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

All the other styles in style.css are rendered fine in IIS, i.e. it is not a "Turn on Static Files" problem in the "Turn On Windows Components" (I already have this on)

Can anyone say why IIS does not render this class?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is an IIS-related problem, since it's not IIS that actually renders HTML -- it's your browser that does so. Thus, check whether your browser requests correct CSS file and that it is indeed in the location it expects it to be in, it's not password-protected, etc.

Comment: IIS seems not to reading from the most recently saved style.css stylesheet, only some previous copy.

is there a cache control that I need to set to refresh?

Comment: Yes, tried F5 and Ctrl-F5 to start with, no difference.

It's strange, all browsers are the same, it just wont reflect recent changes to style.css.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable Failed Request Tracing ( http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis7/ ) to see the exact problem.
You will see there if you are getting 404, in which case your relative URLs are incorrectly set, or if the file is being served from the Cache or any other problem.